# In matlab, is it possible to put methods of classes organised in folders in subdirectories/subfolders?

Tags: matlab, class, path, subdirectory, code-organization

I am new to the option of [organising your classes in class folders](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html) in matlab. In terms of readability, my code benefits from putting methods of the class in separate files, because oftentimes the methods are quite lengthy. Now, I believe it would be even nicer, if I could further organise my code; I'd like to create subdirectories *within* the class folder. The structure I'm looking for is like this (just an example):

```
@Foo/
├──Foo.m/
│
├──staticMethods/
│  ├──staticMethod1.m
│  ├──staticMethod2.m
│
├──privateMethods/
│  ├──privateMethod1.m
```

However, I can't seem to find anything about subfoldering in class folders, nor does it work when I try it, because matlab seems not to find the folders `staticMethods` and `privateMethods`.

Therefore my question: in matlab class folders, is it possible to create subfolders with methods in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Only the directory `Foo` itself is searched for M-files, its subdirectories are not. The exception is a subdirectory called `private`, which can contain M-file functions only visible to the M-files within its parent directory ([documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html)).

Public methods all have to be directly in the `Foo` directory. Private methods can be in the `private` subdirectory. Static methods must be defined within the `classdef` file.

In general, your directory structure can look like this:

```
@Foo/
├──Foo.m
├──A.m
├──B.m
├──private/
│  ├──X.m
│  ├──Y.m
```

`Foo.m` must contain the `classdef` definition for class `Foo` (or, if you go with a pre-classdef class, just its constructor method, though this is not recommended). The `classdef` definition contains all static methods, setters and getters, and any methods that need special access permissions.
Functions `A` and `B` are public methods of `Foo`. `X` and `Y` are functions accessible to any code within `Foo.m`, `A.m`, `B.m`, `X.m` and `Y.m`.

---

To structure your code, you can take longer functions and split them out as private sub-functions, leaving not much more than its declaration in the `classdef`:

```matlab
classdef ClassName
   properties
      ...
   end
   methods
      function obj = C(obj,vararg)
         obj = C_internal(obj,vararg{:});
      end
   end
```

and in a file `private/C_internal.m`:

```matlab
function obj = C_internal(obj,arg2,arg3,arg4,...)
   ...
end
```

(Note the use of `vararg`, which prevents repeating the argument list, duplicated argument lists are a good way of introducing bugs.)

The only issue here is that the documentation still has to sit in `Foo.m`. I personally don't like separating code from documentation, and prefer keeping them together in the same file.